# How to get an object's Oriented Bounding Box (OBB) using script?

Tags: scripting

I  want to get an object OBB's corner points using script.
OBB is orient bound box like this:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### AABB

```
# select a object in object mode first
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

oj  = bpy.context.object
box = oj.bound_box

# Local Space
for el in box:
    for v in el:
        print(v)

print("")

# World Space
p = [oj.matrix_world @ Vector(corner) for corner in box]
print(p)
```

#### OBB

```
# select a object in object mode first
import bpy
import numpy as np
from mathutils import Vector

oj      = bpy.context.object
verts   = [v.co for v in oj.data.vertices]

points = np.asarray(verts)
means = np.mean(points, axis=1)

cov = np.cov(points, y = None,rowvar = 0,bias = 1)

v, vect = np.linalg.eig(cov)

tvect = np.transpose(vect)
points_r = np.dot(points, np.linalg.inv(tvect))

co_min = np.min(points_r, axis=0)
co_max = np.max(points_r, axis=0)

xmin, xmax = co_min[0], co_max[0]
ymin, ymax = co_min[1], co_max[1]
zmin, zmax = co_min[2], co_max[2]

xdif = (xmax - xmin) * 0.5
ydif = (ymax - ymin) * 0.5
zdif = (zmax - zmin) * 0.5

cx = xmin + xdif
cy = ymin + ydif
cz = zmin + zdif

corners = np.array([
    [cx - xdif, cy - ydif, cz - zdif],
    [cx - xdif, cy + ydif, cz - zdif],
    [cx - xdif, cy + ydif, cz + zdif],
    [cx - xdif, cy - ydif, cz + zdif],
    [cx + xdif, cy + ydif, cz + zdif],
    [cx + xdif, cy + ydif, cz - zdif],
    [cx + xdif, cy - ydif, cz + zdif],
    [cx + xdif, cy - ydif, cz - zdif],
])

corners = np.dot(corners, tvect)
center = np.dot([cx, cy, cz], tvect)

corners = [Vector((el[0], el[1], el[2])) for el in corners]

print("local space:")
for el in corners: print(el)

print("")
print("world space:")
mat = oj.matrix_world
for el in corners: print(mat @ el)
```

Comment: I know object.bound_box, but I'm not sure it is OBB bound box or just AABB bound box.

Comment: I updated the both methods. AABB and OBB.

Comment: You calculate that artificially? So the origin code is AABB?

Comment: Yes, Top is AABB, bottom is OBB. Here is a example to use them.  
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/261070/python-how-to-make-box-out-of-selected-verts-bounding-box-in-local-space/261076#261076

Comment: Here is the paper of research by other peope.  https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Dinesh-Manocha/publication/2807460_Collision_Queries_using_Oriented_Bounding_Boxes/links/56cb392008ae5488f0daea80/Collision-Queries-using-Oriented-Bounding-Boxes.pdf?origin=publication_detail

Comment: @X Y Hi I have a questions about the order of OBB verts, I'm trying to get bottom four points of OBB verts, should it be 1, 2, 3 and 4th points of output?

Comment: No, you need to check each point to see which is the lowest.

Comment: @X Y Is this random process?

Comment: For same mesh, the results always same

Comment: Thanks, I found a way to construct bottom polygon using convex hull

Comment: It's worth mentioning that after you apply `matrix_world` to AABB, it's not axis aligned anymore.